# Cursor index out of bounds

Tags: android, cursor

I am encountering cursor index out of bounds exception.

My code is as follows.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String completedInList = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_BUCKET_ITEMS + " WHERE "
                + KEY_BUCKET + " = " + bucketNo + " AND " + KEY_FLAG + " = 1" ;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(completedInList, null);
int completed = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

String totalNoList = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_BUCKET_ITEMS + " WHERE "
                + KEY_BUCKET + " = " + bucketNo;
cursor.close();

Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(totalNoList, null);
int total = Integer.parseInt(cursor2.getString(0));

float percentage = ((float)completed) / total;

cursor2.close();
db.close();
```

I expect that the return value of the sql query is a number that's why I code the index to 0 as follows: `cursor.getString(0)`

But why am I encountering an cursor index out of bounds?

Comment: you should take note that the cursor returned from a query initializes *before* its result indexes. you must at least call `cursor.moveToFirst();` or other move methods to move into the query rows. But this could also result from having no results returned in the query and trying to access columns regardless. This is just something else to take note of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) says  `rawQuery` returns

> A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry

So you seem to need call  `moveToFirst` before using `cursor.getString`